How do I retain the original jpeg image quality when I create a canvas
I have a form that displays a bunch of barcodes in jpeg format. When I right-click on an image and choose "saveAs", the file is saved with the original quality of the jpeg:
<div style="float:left;width:33%;text-align:center;margin:2em 0 0 0;">
    <img class="barcodeImg" src="GenBarcode.asp?height=12&amp;text=AKH32-8-A-YRS" filename="AKH32-8-A-YRS (Adult Fitted Hat).jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</div>

However, when I convert those bardcodes to blobs using a canvas, the canvas renders the barcode as a png, thereby reducing the quality of the image. When I save that canvas, the bardcode is no longer scannable. It has lost a lot of its resolution.
$(`.barcodeImg`).each(function() {
    const img = $(this);
    const cvs = document.createElement(`canvas`);
    cvs.width = img[0].naturalWidth;
    cvs.height = img[0].naturalHeight;
    const ctx = cvs.getContext(`2d`);
    ctx.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
    document.getElementById(`canvasResults`).appendChild(cvs); // <-this results in a low-quality .png.
});

Converting to a blob:
cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
    blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    blob.name = filename;
    }
},`image/jpeg`,1);

The new jpeg image is low res and unscannable.
How do I retain the original quality in the new blob or in the canvas element?

Going from JPEG to JPEG through a canvas will indeed always lower the quality and often raise the size of the output image, because the JPEG compression artifacts of the first image will be rendered as actual pixel data on the canvas and the JPEG compression algorithm will have more varying data to work with when producing the final one. Still, the canvas version shouldn't be different than what you have displayed in the <img> tag. Can you please make a live snippet of the issue?

BTW. png should actually be the better format monochrome images like barcodes and QR-codes both in quality and and in file-size. The canvas size should equal the intrinsic height of the jpeg. If not something in your script is scaling the image down. Try to log the rsults for  img.natruralWidth+height to console.

There is no "quality" setting in JPEG. Some JPEG encoder interfaces hide the complexity of quantization table selection using what they call "quality." If you use different CODECs that same quality setting will not have the same effect.

Where did I mention anything about a "quality" setting? Unhelpful comment
